# the generators of the modular group are S and T

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

The claim is that the modular group $$\Gamma=\langle S,T\rangle$$
with $S=\begin{pmatrix}  0  &-1 \\ 1  & 0    \end{pmatrix}$ and  $T=\begin{pmatrix}  1  &1 \\ 0  & 1    \end{pmatrix}$ .

I do not really  understand the proof by induction .

Let $G$ be the group generated by $S$ and $T$. Now I want to show that  $G =\Gamma$ . The one conclusion is trivial .

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}  a  &b \\ c  & d    \end{pmatrix}\in \Gamma$ .

Then I want to prove by induction on $|c| $ that $A \in G$ .

First if $|c|=0$ then $A=\pm T^b  \in G$ .

Now consider $|c|>0$

$ST^mA=\begin{pmatrix}  -c  &-d \\ a+mc  & b+md    \end{pmatrix}$
, m$\in \mathbb{Z}$

One can choose $m$ such that  $|a+mc|<|c|$ .

Now I do not understand why

$ST^mA \in G$  saying that $A \in G$ .

Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 2):

The argument is not complete. You have to keep on multiplying by $S$ and powers of $T$, so that the absolute value continues decreasing and eventually the lower left entry becomes zero. Now your back in the case $c =0$.

Answer (score 2):

Using $T^m ,S$ you can transform the bottom row $(c,d)$ into $(c,d+mc)$ and $(d+mc,-c)$, this is what you need for the $\gcd$ algorithm, terminating with the bottom row $ = (0,\pm 1)$ which implies the obtained matrix is $\pm T^r$

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the problem is the induction step. Consider this

**Hint:** $X \in G \implies T^{a}S^{b}X \in G$

**Solution:**
$$
ST^mA \in G \implies T^{-m}S^{-1}(ST^mA) \in G \implies A \in G
$$